# Laravel 5.4 - Error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::count()

Tags: php, json, laravel, collections, httpresponse

I get this error some times when i pass collection to my view from composer.

i have this error on this line :

```
@if(!empty($running_out_offers->count()))
  .....
@endif
```

I don't know what's wrong with this and can't debug that because it happens some times even when i didn't manipulate data or etc.

This is my controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Enums\PostType;
use App\Models\Blog\BlogPost;
use App\Models\Campaign;

class WebsiteController extends Controller
{
    function homepage(){

      return view('website.homepage');
    }
}
```

and this is my composer :

```
function compose(View $view)
{

    if ($view->getName() == 'website.homepage') {
        $view->with([
            'running_out_offers'   => $this->runningOutOffers(4),
         ]);
     }
} 

private function runningOutOffers($limit = null,$fields = '')
{
    return $this->remember('runningOutOffers', 1, function () use ($limit,$fields) {
        return offerAndEntity($limit, function ($query) {
            $query->main()->runningOut();
        },null,$fields);
    });
}


   function remember($key, $time, $callback)
{
    return cache()->store('file')->remember('prefix_'.$key, $time, $callback);
}
```

this returns a collection.

can someone tell me whats the problem? :(

Is it possible because of the caching ?!

Edited :

{{ dd($running_out_offers) }}  shows this :

```
 Collection {#1038 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
  0 => Entity {#980 ▼
  #fillable: array:20 [▶]
  #attach: array:1 [▶]
  #presenter: "App\Presenters\EntityPresenter"
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 42807
    "title" => "Offer Title"
    "type" => "SERVICE"
    "is_parent" => 1
    "parent_id" => null
    "attachments" => "{"icon":"fdc839958987caad5ba67016fcd77eaf.jpg"}"
    "available_children" => 2
    "sold" => 21
    "is_available" => 1
  ]
  #original: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▶]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #forceDeleting: false
  #public_path: "/home/shikoff/public_html"
  #upload_path: "/home/shikoff/public_html/upload/entity"
  #upload_relative_path: "upload/entity"
  #presenterInstance: null
}
```

]
}

Comment: could you `{{ dd($running_out_offers) }}` in the view and show us what it shows.

Comment: I edited the post,now you can see. @Wreigh

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't view the image since my network's proxy blocks it. :( (I can't control the network lol)

Comment: Thats no problem :) i copied that @Wreigh

Comment: last thing, can you provide a bit of the stack trace? this is somehow mind-boggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try-

```
@if(count($running_out_offers)>0)
  .....
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks @Sohel0415 , it works but i have to wait till not seeing that error again.

Answer (score 1):

You must return query builder to use count function and don't return collection